# função incluir em LISP

Tags: lisp

Estou com duvidas de como fazer uma função  INCLUIR em programação LISP. consigo setar um nome de alguém , mas não consigo incluir alguma informação adicional.

A função incluirá informações adicionais de uma pessoa em uma lista. Segue o codigo:

```
(setq AGENDA 'nil)
(setq AGENDA ( incluir AGENDA '(Isabel 3233876)))
```

Este incluir não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida, o que essa função faria, tem como dar um exemplo? Poste também o código que você já fez, assim dá pra ter uma ideia melhor do problema (sugiro [edit] a pergunta com o código).

Comment: Então, que lista é essa, como está representada, onde está armazenada? E essas "informações adicionais" são o que, é um conjunto fixo de propriedades, são propriedades arbitrárias? É por isso que ajuda se você postar o seu código atual e um exemplo do que você quer.

Comment: a função incluirá informações adicionais de uma pessoa em uma lista. Segue o codigo: (setq AGENDA 'nil) (setq AGENDA ( incluir AGENDA '(Isabel 3233876))) este incluir não estou conseguindo fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Lisp, uma lista possui duas partes: a "cabeça" (`car`) e a "cauda" (`cdr`). A cabeça é um elemento comum da lista, e a cauda é o resto da lista (ou `nil`, se a lista acabou). Você pode criar uma lista implicitamente, usando:

```
(a b c d)
```

Ou explicitamente, usando `.`:

```
(a . (b . (c . (d . nil))))
```

Sendo assim, se sua lista `AGENDA` contém `nil`, e você quer adicionar um elemento na mesma, substitua-a por uma nova lista, com o elemento novo na cabeça e o elemento antigo na cauda:

```
(setq AGENDA `(("Isabel" 3233876) . ,AGENDA))
```

Tudo o que resta então é transformar isso numa função:

```
(defun incluir (lista elemento) `(,elemento . ,lista))

(setq AGENDA (incluir AGENDA '("Isabel" 3233876)))
```

[Exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/aC9ZMT). P.S. Tenho pouca experiência com Lisp, certamente existe um meio mais simples de se criar essas listas sem ser com *backtick*/vírgula, mas não me recordo...

Comment: Você pode usar a função cons, que insere no começo de uma lista. `(setf agenda (cons '("Isabel" 3233876) agenda))` (setq também funciona, mas até onde eu saiba setf é mais comum.